# Replication Existing Objects- AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to replicate existing objects (between different accounts) from two of my buckets in AWS S3.

I am following the steps in [1].

For, let's say bucket 'A', it works and replicated successfully.
For, let's say bucket 'B', constantly fail.

Do you have any suggestion? or steps that I should follow? or where did I make a mistake?

Steps I have taken.

1. Created Replication rule. (new objects uploaded to source bucket get replicated to destination bucket successfully ).
2. Destination bucket permission updated.
3. Created IAM role
4. set up 'Inventory Configuration'
5. imported data provided from step 4 above (including `MSCK REPAIR TABLE <databasename.tablename>`) into Athena.
6. Run the scripts as provided after updating.

   a. AWS_PROFILE=
   b. REGION=
   c. SUBNET_ID=
   d. EMR_CLUSTER_NAME=
   e. INVENTORY_BUCKET=
   f. GLUE_DATABASE_NAME=
   g. ATHENA_TABLE_NAME=
   h. INVENTORY_DATE=
   i. PARTITIONS='1'

   `$ git clone https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-s3-crr-preexisting-objects.`
   `$ ./launch emr.sh`

And I keep failing to replicate in this bucket. any suggestion is welcome.

Thx.

### Reference

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/trigger-cross-region-replication-of-pre-existing-objects-using-amazon-s3-inventory-amazon-emr-and-amazon-athena/